# After update, which Vowpal Wabbit version am I running?

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I had a year old version of VW that I'm running from terminal with the standard `vw` syntax.
I installed the latest version, by downloading the git and running `make`. When I now run `vw`, am I running the newer version of do I need to update an alias or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Which Vowpal Wabbit am I running?***

This is a shell dependent answer. For most shells this should work:

```
which vw
```

If you're using `sh` compatible shells like `bash`, this should also work:

```
type vw
```

***Which version is it?***

```
vw --version
```

***Please don't use shell aliases to switch between versions.***

Aliases aren't preserved across shell invocations, so vw utilities such as `vw-hypersearch` for example, may not use the version you think you are using (because you have some misconceived `vw` alias set somewhere).

Instead, you need to first 'install' (basically copy) your `vowpalwabbit/vw` executable to a standard location (e.g. using `make install` from the same place you ran `make`), finally make sure your PATH includes the directory you installed `vw` in e.g. by prepending `/usr/local/bin` to it:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Better: put the above in your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent) so you don't need to repeatedly set it when you log in.